# Remove elements from array above an index AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, arrays

Is there a quick helper for removing elements from an array above a certain index in AngularJS?

For instance:

You have an array with 5 elements:

```
[0][1][2][3][4]
```

I want to remove all elements above index 2:

Result

```
[0][1][2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
array.slice(start, end)
```

In your case, something like this:

```
array.slice(0, -2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the intel!

Comment: I used the following `$scope.vm.NodesMap.splice(level + 1, $scope.vm.NodesMap.length);`